# Azure Data Factory Copy Activity Rest API JSON response date format incorrect

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to copy data from rest api source using the azure copy activity. I have used Rest Api as source and csv as target. But the json response I am receiving is having the date as below format:
{Createddate: /date(345667999)/}

But when I hit preview data its giving the correct date format.(yyyy-mm-dd).

Can anyone suggest why is it like this? Is there any workaround to get the date value with correct format in the copy activity itself?

Answer (score 0):

In the mappings tab of the Copy activity, you will need to set the target column type to either date or string. Please refer the below screenshot :

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have the target as sql server and  column of datatype date.

But I am getting the below error:

Created date contains invalid date. Createddate(/date(345667999)/) is not in correct format.

Please suggest.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? Facing the samen issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/10653466/chiragmishra-msft Is there a workaround for this?DataFactory seems to have not resolved this issue. Thanks

Comment: I have the same issue and I write into json where I cannot set the type which ends into that same issue